# Create a link on Document Library Context menu targeting Doc Library & File Type

Tags: sharepoint-online, ecb-menu

I am creating a custom action on a SharePoint Online site. I would like a button to pop up for all docx file types in a specific document library, not all document libraries.

it looks like I only have the choice either File Type OR choose List ID, not both. Is it possible to do both somehow?

```
<CustomAction
  RegistrationType = "ContentType"
  RegistrationId=">
</CustomAction>
```

The above will show in every document library for docx OR:

```
<CustomAction
  RegistrationType = "List"
  RegistrationId="listId">
</CustomAction>
```

the above will show for all file types on a document library

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add your action only to specific document library. No additional parameters needed.
[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246201.aspx) you can see that SP.List object has userCustomActions property. It is what you need. 
You can add custom action like this by js from browser console.
[Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185004(v%3Doffice.14)#adding-a-user-custom-action-for-list-items-using-ecmascript-javascript-jscript) good guide how to do that but I copy-paste just in case
:

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function createUserCustomActionList() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    this.oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle('My List');
    var collUserCustomAction = oList.get_userCustomActions();

    var oUserCustomAction = collUserCustomAction.add();
    oUserCustomAction.set_location('EditControlBlock');
    oUserCustomAction.set_sequence(100);
    oUserCustomAction.set_title('My First User Custom Action');
    oUserCustomAction.set_url(siteUrl + '/_layouts/MyPage.aspx');
    oUserCustomAction.update();

    clientContext.load(oList, 'Title' ,'UserCustomActions');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Custom action created for ' + this.oList.get_title());}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Change list name to yours, action settings to yours and execute this in browser console on any list item form (here you have all scripts loaded - SP.ClientContext and etc must work here - may be list view also have all scripts - I don't remember).